# Ignoring SIGPIPE doesn't work iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sigpipe

My App returns a `signal 13: Broken pipe: 13` error and the reason is probably a serverside issue, I'm trying to ignore SIGPipes in my App to see if it works, however xcode won't let me do it. It just keeps on giving sigpipes.

I added the following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // We expect write failures to occur but we want to handle them where
    // the error occurs rather than in a SIGPIPE handler.
    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't help at all and the App just freezes anyway.
What am I missing here?

Comment: You also need to handle socket read / write errors from what I read.

Answer (score 0):

Allright, after a couple of days I found out that the `signal 13` sigPIPE was fixed and instead it was returning a signal 9 which means out of memory. This was not an issue with my App but with the devices memory since other apps returned this too.